# HERE Map/MapView without using MapFragment popupBackstack issues

Tags: android, android-fragments, sdk, here-api

I have one Activity and loading two fragments (MapScreenFragment and OtherFragment) to the backstack. The issue that I am encountering is that when I start to popup some fragment from the backstack the MapScreenFragment shows black screen.

Should I set anew Map to the MapView?

```
map = new Map();
mapView.setMap(map);
```

> XML Layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

> Fragment Class

```
public class MapScreenFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");

    if(isMapEngineInitialized && mapEngine != null) {
        mapEngine.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, " onResume Map engine reference " + mapEngine.getResourceReferenceCount());
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");

    if(isMapEngineInitialized && mapEngine != null) {
        mapEngine.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, " onPause Map engine reference " + mapEngine.getResourceReferenceCount());
    }
}
}

/***** added ******/
OnEngineInitListener onEngineInitListener = new OnEngineInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {
        if(error == Error.NONE) {
            isMapEngineInitialized = true;

            if(map == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, " Map is null");
                map = new Map();
            }

            mapView.setMap(map);
            mapView.setMapMarkerDragListener(MapScreenFragment.this);

            map = mapView.getMap();
            map.addTransformListener(MapScreenFragment.this);

            mapGesture = mapView.getMapGesture();
            mapGesture.setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
            mapGesture.addOnGestureListener(MapScreenFragment.this);

            setUpMap();

            Log.d(TAG, "MapEngine initialized! " + mapEngine.getResourceReferenceCount());

        }

    }
};
```

> MainActivity Backpressed and adding Fragments

```
mapFragment = new MapScreenFragment ();
mFragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame_layout, mapFragment , mdmFragmentID);
mFragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
mFragmentTransaction.commit();



otherFragment = new OtherFragment ();
mFragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_layout, otherFragment , mdmFragmentID);
mFragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);mFragmentTransaction.commit();


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Back stack count " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
    if( getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
        finish();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, which SDK release are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure MapView#onResume() is called for the case isMapEngineInitialized == false, and especially when the MapEngine#onEngineInit listener is called back.

Normally, the application lifecycle calls onResume() much earlier than the engine has initialized. If the MapView#onResume() is not called, the underlying rendering constructs will not be started. Please refer to our sample apps for an example.

Also, why not use nested Fragments? You can always embed a MapFragment into another fragment so the lifecycle is automatically handled.

Comment: isn't that a bad practice to have a nested fragments? Another reason why I didn't use MapFragment is because I want to separate other view objects from the main Activity like search bar and popup views etc.

Comment: I believe after Android 4.2, nested fragments are quite normal and well supported. It should be part of the support-library.too. Pleas see https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Comment: Which SDK release are you seeing this problem?

Comment: I am tried what you suggested but MapFragment is getting UNKNOWN error when initializing.

Comment: Did you add in the appid, appcode and permission string? And any adb logcat logs? Perhaps something threw an exception?

Comment: I fixed the problem but now if i put the fragment inside the getChildFragmentManager() and pop  it back. It doesn't show the MapFragment and managing child fragment seems complicated so I went back to MapView implementation. 

I got some issue managing Mapview's (DragListener, GestureListener)  when used in a Fragment. If I add and popping out from the back stack the Listeners are not functioning.

-- code edited